# Windows Phone 8 secure connection through Azure, to an on-premise web service

Tags: web-services, security, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am working on a WP 8 app which I would like to connect to an on-premise(local) web service. I have managed to do so using simple BasicHttpBinding without secuirty and Azure Service Bus Relay, but i cant manage to make a secure connection. WP 8 only support BasicHttpBinding, and thats my biggest problem so far.

I understand that Azure mobile service is an efficent and easy way to securly connect your WP 8 app to the cloud. Is it possible to access an on-premise web service through Azure mobile service? And if possible, could it be done without exposing all the content of the local service publically via Azure Service bus relay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this securely from WP8 -- I'm not quite sure why it's not working -- but even if you had to roll something yourself, it should be possible (example, check out this post from Michael Collier on doing something similar: http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/azure-sb-and-wp7/)

To the question, though, WAMS (Windows Azure Mobile Services) is definitely easy to use, but it wouldn't be feasible to do what you want -- that is, to be a public endpoint in this fashion.  In short, WAMS gives you an easy to use CRUD interface to data that happens to also expose features for authentication and notifications, and at the same time gives you some server-side javascript to do custom work -- such as calling out to other services, sending emails or notifications, etc.

But, each request into WAMS is essentially mapped to a CRUD operation on a database table.  While you could likely 'inject' a simple call, this isn't what you want.  It sounds like using the service bus is the right way to do this and should be possible...

Comment: Got it working with the relay, but still have problems. Now login(auth) problems, which the relay forces me to have on premise. I rather have it in the cloud as with WAMS. Can I 'inject' a simple call which do not affect the WAMS database? Will the 'injection' bypass the database tables or update them too?